# What is the equation for when a project will end given this formula for how fast work is done?

Tags: integration

I want to calculate the rate at which work gets done on a project.

On each week some work is done and some new work is generated. The new work generated is directly proportional to the amount of work remaining in the project.

**Work done on project**

$dW  = (cW - R) dt$

```
W = work remaining
R = rate of work
c = constant representing churn rate
```

How do I calculate when the project ends?

**EDIT**

*Edited to remove original sign error where I had: $dW  = (R - cW) dt$*

Comment: Why the downvote? Except for the sign issue, this seems like an OK question.

Comment: Sorry, there was an error in the calculation; I've corrected the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general solution of this ordinary linear differential equation is

$$W=\frac Rc+a\mathrm e^{ct}\;.$$

Thus, if the initial workload is above $R/c$, work will pile up exponentially ($a\gt0$), whereas if the initial workload is below $R/c$, it will decrease exponentially ($a\lt0$), but the rate won't exceed $R$ before the work becomes $0$. The time $T$ to finish as a function of the initial workload is given by

$$W_0=W(t=0)=\frac Rc+a\;,$$

$$a=W_0-\frac Rc\;,$$

$$0=W(t=T)=\frac Rc+a\mathrm e^{cT}=\frac Rc+\left(W_0-\frac Rc\right)\mathrm e^{cT}\;,$$

$$\left(\frac Rc-W_0\right)\mathrm e^{cT}=\frac Rc\;,$$

$$\mathrm e^{cT}=\frac{\frac Rc}{\frac Rc-W_0}=\frac{1}{1-\frac{cW_0}R}\;,$$

$$cT=\log\frac{1}{1-\frac{cW_0}R}=-\log\left(1-\frac{cW_0}R\right)\;,$$

$$T=-\frac{\log\left(1-\frac{cW_0}R\right)}c\;,$$

where $\log$ denotes the natural logarithm.

Comment: This looks great thank you - it behaves as I expected and also reminded me how to do an integration of $dy/dx = y$. I have one question though which is when I was working it through I initially made the same sign error at the end as you did. Your version is right but I can't see where the negatives come from in my workings

Comment: @Peter: I've written out the steps in more detail. The penultimate line uses $\log(1/x)=-\log x$.

Comment: Ahh yes, I see now - thanks very much btw, this was my first question on math.stackexchange and you made it incredibly fulfilling - even reignited my enthusiasm more maths (my degree was in physics). Much appreciated

Comment: @Peter: You're very welcome. My degree was in physics, too :-)